# Is there any way to print something for a ValueError?

Tags: python-3.x, math

Im using this code in python 3.5 for the 'quadratic formula';

```
def quad(a,b,c):
    d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
    num1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    num2 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    print  ("Your solutions are", num1, "and", num2)
```

The code works fine, but is there any way for me to add a print function that displays ("Math Error"), when the values of num1 and num2 show up as "ValueError: math domain error"

Im looking for something like this...

```
if num1 or num2 = ValueError: # I can't figure out how to 'word' this
    print ("Math Error")
```

Comment: You could test for `d<0`? And even print the then complex solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an average normal exception handler

```
import sys

def quad(a,b,c):
    try:
        d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
        num1 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        num2 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        print  ("Your solutions are", num1, "and", num2)
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Math error", e, file=sys.stderr)
```